# Reading contents of the file in java and check on parameters

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am familiar with reading contents of the file in java using Buffered Reader and Scanner, here i am trying to Read the contents of a file and then check if the variables in the file does not have null values.

Like in file read.txt consider parameters

```
name=jen,add=avenue,age=25,email=@20212.com.
```

If the parameters are name,add,age,email are null or no values it should display error message. I can easily read the contents of the file, but I am stuck with checking if the file parameters have no values how to proceed this in java. Any idea that would be great for me.

Comment: can you put the code snippet where you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If the file really has the form you described above (`name=jen,add=avenue,age=25,email=@20212.com`) split the string you read first at `,`, then at `=` and check which attributes have which value (if the value length is 0 or the string is `"Null"`, you know there was nothing specified, and you can display the error).

Look at this untested example:

```
String[] attrs = fileString.split(",");
for (String attr : attrs) {
   String[] elements = attr.split("="); 
   String attrName = elements[0];
   String value = elements[1];
   if (value.length == 0 || value.equals("Null") {
      displayError();
   }
}
```

You have to watch out that none of your attributes/values contain `,` or `=`, in this case this approach would fail. But then again, not many of your attributes should contain these characters, and if they do you can change your delimiter to something like `\\\` which is even more unlikely ;).

Comment: I was trying to do this thing through a java Properties file.

Comment: `Properties properties = new Properties();
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("example.properties"));
properties.load(stream);
stream.close();
String value = properties.getProperty("name");`, directly from wikipedia. Now just do the above check for the `value` string. Take a look at [Wikipedia on properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) and accept the answer if it solves your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should going through your file, and transform each line as a string. After that you should just check if the string contains the word Null. Seems pretty simple said like that but I can't test code just right now.